# How to manage user/role in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I know that MVC5 (Visual Studio 2013) has no admin interface for user/role management, My question is: How to create new users, assign roles to user, add roles, etc in a production server. In other words when my web application was ready it was published to an IIS, now I want to know how register new admins users for example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: No have official solution, its is hard, no make scaffolding for identity objects, identity objects no use keys by default. Use custom class for manage users, custom entities, custom sessions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to manage users for your web application, since MVC4 there is a solid implementation of such features under **WebSecurity**. **WebSecurity** will provide you with all the fundamental functions to create and manage your your users and roles. Unfortunately it does not provide you with an user interface. That you have to build on your own

Comment: OK, thanks you a lot for your answer, but my question now is: exist any documentation about how to build a user interface to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect answer of your question but you might want to take a look at Microsoft Identity 2.0. It comes with a built in User and Role manager with views where you can create, edit, delete and assign both roles and users.

Create a new empty MVC application and use the PM Console to install the sample project.

More info here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx